# Android Skype Intent

Tags: android, skype

i am currently developing a simple app on android. I have an imageview (Skype Intent) with a setonclicklistener. When someone clicks on this imageview appears the dialog "Complete action using...." . The dialog contains the skype option which is the desired one, but also contains all the apps which i have developed on my computer. When someone hits the imageview i want to has the option to complete the action only with skype application. If is possible to disappear the  dialog "Complete action using..." at all and open skype automatically it would be better.

The skype Intent:

```
final Intent sky = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        sky.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + ""));
        ImageView imSky = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imSky.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(sky); 
            }
        });
```

Android Manifest.xml with the 2 intent filter which i have,

```
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="skype" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This code will launch Skype, is that what you want?

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");
if (intent != null)
{
    // start the activity
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    // bring user to the market
    // or let them choose an app?
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+"com.skype.raider"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

i found the solution. Just removed 

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

from manifest.xml. Now it doesnt appear "Complete action using" dialog and redirct to skype application.